# How to open the terminal in Atom?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, atom-editor

How to open the terminal in Atom? Do I need to install a plug-in?

If possible, I also would like to know how to use shortcut keys to open the terminal.

Comment: You can search pretty easily for packages in Atom, either with Google or by searching Atom itself. [This seems like a good one for what you want](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus)

Comment: Thanks, I use another plugin of the https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal.both the same result

Answer (score 154):

*In* the Atom IDE:

1. Open file>settings
2. Click "+" (install)
3. Search for a terminal package called "platformio-ide-terminal"
4. Click "install".
5. Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to toggle the terminal

Comment: Could be easier to install it from: https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal

Comment: You can press "Ctrl+Shift+P" then search with  "install package" to help u open  the installing page , tested on linux

Comment: I'm going to use platformio-ide-terminal and not atom-ide-terminal as someone else suggest in this thread, as the first one has almost 8M download and 961 star at the moment, the second one just 80K download and just 9 star :)

Comment: The new path to "Install Packages" is "Edit > Preferences > Install".

Comment: This is clearly the most up-to-date answer. However "the terminal" is a package implementation that may not behave the same way as your OS terminal of choice. For example I use [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) on Linux which has many helpful features like clicking on `some/very/long/path/to/file/` highlights the whole line, copies the text to the clipboard in 1 go. The keyboard commands for copy/paste are different than those used in the package's terminal. This can make using it a little more cumbersome. Still, this is better in than no terminal.

Comment: Too bad Atom doesn't have a terminal built in like VS Code. They should realize that this makes the competitor more attractive.

Comment: I see the terminal uses powershell. 
Is there no way to change it to command prompt or WSL? The problem I have with powershell is that it is not picking up my git. Tells me project is not a git repo. But it is.

Answer (score 47):

**For Windows follow the below steps**

(1)go to file>setting and click on install
[image]

(2) then type "platformio-ide-terminal" in packages and hit install
[image]
(3) after finish install restart atom and press

```
 ctrl + ~ for opening the terminal `~` is the key below `Esc`
```

[image]

welcome ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that is also relevant for macOS

Answer (score 21):

*Edit: I no longer use Atom. The plugins I originally recommended here have all apparently ceased to be maintained. I've updated this answer with the suggestions in the comments, but please note I haven't tried any of these and will no longer be maintaining this answer.*

*Please check the comments or other answers for more up-to-date recommendations.*

---

There are a number of Atom packages which give you access to the terminal from within Atom. Try a few out to find the best option for you.

### Open a terminal *in* Atom:

If you want to open a terminal panel *in* Atom, try [`platformio-ide-terminal`](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal). Use the keyboard shortcut `` ctrl-` `` to open a new terminal instance.

### Open an external terminal *from* Atom:

If you just want a shortcut to open your external terminal from within Atom, try [`open-terminal-here`](https://atom.io/packages/open-terminal-here). You can use `ctrl-alt-t` to open your external terminal in the current file's directory, or `ctrl-alt-shift-t` to open the terminal in the project's root directory.

Comment: Pretty sure `terminal-plus` is no longer working, it has not been updated since 2015 and there are several open issues in the repo saying it is broken.

Comment: Thanks @MorganRodgers, I've updated to replace with a fork of `terminal-plus` called `atom-ide-terminal`.

Comment: For opening your system terminal from Atom, use [`open-terminal-here`](https://atom.io/packages/open-terminal-here) nowadays instead of `atom-terminal`, the latter is i think just not working anymore, at least on GNU/Linux and hasn't been updated in 5 years.

Comment: Fork of atom-ide-terminal is platformio-ide-terminal

Comment: Looks like both `terminal-plus` and `atom-ide-terminal` are obsolete these days. For now, only [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal)(fork of `terminal-plus`) is working for me.

Answer (score 15):

Atom currently does not have a built-in terminal(that I know of), so you would have to install an additional package such as `platformio-ide-terminal`.

*The following screenshots were taken on a mac.*

1. Click on **Atom** and select Preferences
   [image]
2. In the Settings tab that appears, click on the add icon `+` to Install a new package
   [image]
3. A search bar will appear. Most packages should have the feature you desire in their name, so you can begin to type those keywords to see suggestions. In this case if you already know the name, just enter it there
   [image]
4. Click Install

Comment: Any particular reason for that terminal plugin and not the many others on the store?

Comment: @mousetail I don't actually recall as this was years ago and I now use VS Code. But I am sure there are many other great options by now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really surprised that everywhere I find recommends this one extension while there are so many

Answer (score 7):

First, you should install "platformio-ide-terminal": Open **"Preferences ⌘,"** >> Click **"+ Install"** >> In **"Search packages"** type **"platformio-ide-terminal"** >> Click **"Install"**.

And *answering exactly the question.* If you have previously installed, just use:

- Shortcut: `` ctrl-` `` or Option+Command+T (⌥⌘T)
- by Menu: Go to Packages > platformio-ide-terminal [or other] > New terminal

Comment: Help me understand! Have you try on Mac, Windows or Linux? Did you install ide terminal first? On Mac works for me...

Comment: this is a duplicate answer as @brett bristow

Answer (score 4):

In current versions of Mac Catalina

1. go to packages tab --> Settings View ---> Install Packages/Themes ---> +Install button --> add "platformio-ide-terminal"
2. control ~ to get the terminal

Comment: yet another duplicate answer

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to install a package just for that purpose so I ended up using this in my `init.coffee`:

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'open-terminal', ->
  file = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getPath()
  dir = atom.project.getDirectoryForProjectPath(file).path
  spawn 'mate-terminal', ["--working-directory=#{dir}"], {
    detached: true
  }
```

With that, I could map `ctrl-shift-t` to the `open-terminal` command and it opens a mate-terminal.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for.  Would be so great if it could some how fake docking itself to the bottom of the Atom window, perhaps by resizing, but that would probably be way complex. Also, the working directory didn't work for me and it opened scoped to `~/.atom`

Comment: mate-terminal actually has a --geometry option. With `--geometry=1000x10+0+2000` it puts the terminal flush on the lower screen border about 10 lines high, full width (27" display).

Answer (score 1):

And if you end up here in 2022 wondering what should you do for Atom on the latest Mac OS follow these steps:

1. Installation:
   [image]
2. Usage :
   Once installed in order to open the terminal press ctr+`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your Atom IDE
2. press ctrl+shift+P and search for "platformio-ide-terminal" package
3. press install
4. once installed press ctrl+~ (tilde above tab key in a standard keyboard)
5. terminal opens enjoy!!!